# Loading H&R Block Tax Software

Tags: software-installation

Why do I keep getting a pop up that is titled "Archive Manager" with an error message stating "An error occurred while loading the archive" when I am trying to download the H&R Block Tax Software?

Answer (score 1):

From what can be found on the H&R Block website [(http://www.hrblock.com/tax-software/)](http://www.hrblock.com/tax-software/) the software is produced only for Windows and Mac.  It may work in Wine, but that would be far from certain.  If you wish to use this software, you will probably need to load Windows into a virtual machine or dual boot setup, and run the software from that operating system.